# h2db connection to pentaho report designer is giving error

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, h2db, server-mode

[h2db is connecting thorugh the console in Server mode as you can see the picture by clicking on this line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22wvk.png)

[But the issue is coming here in the pentaho report designer while giving host name or port number as you can see the picture by clicking on this line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVZIw.png)

**following error occurs in penatho report designer when the connection is tested.**

```
Error connecting to database [sampleConnection] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.h2.Driver)
General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""h2:tcp:""" [50000-196]


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.h2.Driver)
General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""h2:tcp:""" [50000-196]


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:466)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:364)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:335)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:325)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2734)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:591)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:71)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:250)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:254)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:159)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.setVisible(CommonDialog.java:230)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:158)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:798)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:71)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.EditQueryAction.performEdit(EditQueryAction.java:135)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.editor.structuretree.DataReportTree$EditQueryDoubleClickHandler.mouseClicked(DataReportTree.java:386)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.h2.Driver)
General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""h2:tcp:""" [50000-196]

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:579)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:450)
    ... 120 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""h2:tcp:""" [50000-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:268)
    at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:352)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:130)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:561)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "h2:tcp:"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:740)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:1197)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:79)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:115)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:453)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:334)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
    ... 126 more

Hostname       : jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/shared/
Port           : 9092
Database name  : test
```

Comment: i never worked with h2db but by looking at you screen-shot i can defiantly say that you can-not specify the host_name like this, you are giving local drive reference which is wrong.

Comment: thanks for replying @WorkingHard.. Do you know how to make h2db connection with Pentaho Report Designer in Ubuntu?

Comment: as per my understanding whether linux or Windows, connection process will remain same.through i never worked with it so won't be able to say confirm thing.

Comment: I am giving same credentials in the h2db connection to PRD in ubuntu but it is not working, h2db console is working properly but issue is coming in PRD connection with h2db. Reports is not fetching data from h2db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this issue. appreciate those who gave a look into this.

[Click on this link to see how this is done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Qjy.png)